# stop bcp adding line numbers by default

Tags: bcp

I have a bcp export

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell
'bcp "SELECT * FROM ##tmptable" queryout "c:\phonegapdownload\phonegap.js" -c -t, -T'
```

my problem is that it adds line number to the export file

```
1,{ "id": "500020", "type": "0" },
2,{ "id": "500025", "type": "0"},
3,{ "id": "500043", "type": "0"},
```

can anyone tell me how to stop it doing this

thanks

Answer (score 0):

My hunch is that it's returning the row id rather than the row number.  Perhaps change to just get the row you need and see if that fixes it.

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell
'bcp "SELECT [yourJsonRowName] FROM ##tmptable" queryout "c:\phonegapdownload\phonegap.js" -c -t, -T'
```